# "FAILED (remote: 'size too large')" when flashing recovery image of Pixel Experience (Android 13) on Redmi 10

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot, redmi, pixel-experience

I'm trying to flash Pixel Experience (Android 13) on Redmi 10.

```
PS F:\android\Redmi 10\codice per il recupero del telefono\platform-tools> fastboot flash -S 4056M boot PixelExperience\recovery.img
Sending 'boot_a' (131072 KB)                       OKAY [  3.029s]
Writing 'boot_a'                                   FAILED (remote: 'size too large')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

This is the error after starting the `fastboot flash boot`. I also tried `-S` which should crop the partition, but it doesn't work.

If you have any ideas to solve the problem, I gladly accept it.

Comment: That command `fastboot flash boot <recovery_filename>.img` don't look correct to me. A recovery image should not be flashed to a bootloader section.

Comment: @Robert apparently [the official guide](https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/fog/install/) does mention `boot`.

Comment: Seems to be a workaround to compensate the missing recovery partition, so the the recovery is a recovery including bootloader? But as it is way larger it is not unexpected that it does not fit into the bootloader partition. May be there are devices and/or fastboot tools that ignore this and just flash it. or the manual is simply wrong (automatically generated).

Comment: As it is stated on the official guide   "NOTE: Outdated fastboot releases dropped legacy A/B support, so it might attempt to flash to boot__a / boot__b rather than boot_a / boot_b if you try to flash boot. In this case, you must update fastboot to a release newer than or equal to 31.0.2. Alternatively, you can manually specify which slot to flash to based on what slot fastboot failed to flash to. For example, if fastboot fails to flash to boot__a, you must flash to boot_a."

Comment: Note there are 2 underscores in `boot__a` and so on